# JQuery Scroll Event keeps firing when you scroll more

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a scroll event that fires when the user scrolls to a certain point on the site. It works until you hit that point and want to keep scrolling, then it will fire continuously with every single scroll. I want to fire ONE time and then just not fire anymore.

```
    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var y_scroll_pos = window.pageYOffset;
    var scroll_pos_test = 450;  // set to whatever you want it to be

    if(y_scroll_pos > scroll_pos_test) {
      alert("hey you hit it");
    }
});
```

I set up a demo below:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/td4p3p0q/)

Comment: @nnnnnn yes I tried to add a var that set it to false inside but it didn't fix it. Maybe offer a solution instead of pointing that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it keeps firing with every scroll - you haven't removed the scroll event handler, and if the user keeps scrolling down the `if` condition will continue to be true for subsequent scroll events. Note that the handler is also firing for every scroll *before* the user reaches that point of the page, it just doesn't do anything noticeable because of the `if`.

> *"I want to fire ONE time and then just not fire anymore."*

The obvious solution would be to just call the [`.off()` method](http://api.jquery.com/off/) to remove the scroll handler once it's no longer required:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var y_scroll_pos = window.pageYOffset;
    var scroll_pos_test = 450;  // set to whatever you want it to be

    if(y_scroll_pos > scroll_pos_test) {
      $(window).off('scroll');  // <--- add this
      alert("hey you hit it");
    }
});
```

Comment: This works great too, I honestly did not know there was an off method. Thanks for teaching me something!

Comment: You're welcome. I'd recommend taking half an hour to browse through the [list of all jQuery methods and selectors](http://api.jquery.com/) - don't try to memorise it all or anything, but just make a mental note of whichever methods seem useful to you.

Answer (score 2):

You can set a variable once the scroll point has been met, and only alert if that variable isn't set.

```js
 var scrolled = false;
 $(window).on('scroll', function() {
     var y_scroll_pos = window.pageYOffset;
     var scroll_pos_test = 450;  // set to whatever you want it to be
 
     if(y_scroll_pos > scroll_pos_test && !scrolled) {
       alert("hey you hit it");
       scrolled = true;
     }
 });
```

```css
.scroll-text{
  Height:1000px;
  width:100px;
  background-color:Yellow; 
}

.scroll-target{
  Height:600px;
  width:100px;
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scroll-text">
  <p>
      Scroll Down
  </p>
</div>
<div class="scroll-target">
  <p>
      You found me!
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do, I was putting the "var scrolled" in the wrong spot this whole time.  Thanks!

Comment: @Jiroscopes np!